# not selector inside parent element

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I need `console.log` if `.overtitle` is clicked, but excluding the checkbox inside. If checkbox is clicked I need just it to be checked/unchecked, without `console.log`.

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work. Clicking on the checkbox fires `console.log`.

```js
$('.overtitle').not('.checkpart').click(function() {
  console.log('323');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='overtitle'>
  <input class='checkpart' type="checkbox" name="part" value="banner00">
  BANNERS
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on the checkbox you always also click on the `.overtitle`. One solution for this is to check inside the click event for `event.target`

```js
$('.overtitle').click(function(event){
    if(event.target.className == 'checkpart') {
        return;
    }
    console.log('323');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='overtitle'>
<input class='checkpart' type="checkbox" name="part" value="banner00">BANNERS</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Theres a few ways you can do this.

Firstly you could use the `e.target` property to check which element was actually clicked:

```js
$('.overtitle').click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('.checkpart')) {
    console.log('323');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overtitle">
  <input class="checkpart" type="checkbox" name="part" value="banner00"> 
  BANNERS
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can place a separate event handler on the checkbox which stops the event propagating up the DOM:

```js
$('.overtitle').click(function(e) {
    console.log('323');
});

$('.overtitle .checkpart').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overtitle">
  <input class="checkpart" type="checkbox" name="part" value="banner00"> 
  BANNERS
</div>
```

Finally, you could wrap the text in a `label` element, and only attach the event to that:

```js
$('.overtitle label').click(function(e) {
    console.log('323');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overtitle">
  <input class="checkpart" type="checkbox" name="part" id="part" value="banner00"> 
  <label for="part">BANNERS</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Prevent event bubbling up to the DOM tree for the checkbox using [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method.

```js
$('.overtitle').click(function() {
  console.log('323');
}).find('.checkpart').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='overtitle'><input class='checkpart' type="checkbox" name="part" value="banner00">BANNERS</div>
```

---

Or check the [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) element(which propagated the event) is not the checkbox.

```js
$('.overtitle').click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is(':not(.checkpart)'))
    console.log('323');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='overtitle'><input class='checkpart' type="checkbox" name="part" value="banner00">BANNERS</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write two separate event handler for each like

```
$(document).on('click','.overtitle',function(e) {
    console.log('323');
});

$(document).on('click','.checkpart',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The `stopPropagation()` prevents any event handler of parents elements of that element to be executed